# PHPExcel gets wrong timezone even after setting date_default_timezone_set

Tags: php, timezone, phpexcel

I'm using http://phpexcel.codeplex.com in one of my project, and I have come into an issue.
I want to write the time() value inside a cell, which I am doing with :

```
function writeTimeLine($objActiveSheet, &$lineNumber, $timeStart, $timeEnd, $duration, $category, $client, $date, $comment)
{
    $objActiveSheet->setCellValue('A'.$lineNumber, PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel( $timeStart ));
    $objActiveSheet->getStyle('A'.$lineNumber)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME4);
}
```

The $objActiveSheet refers to $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()

And the result in Excel is:

20:27:39

When in real on the computer I'm testing it it's 16:27:39

So it's an issue with the timezone (I'm living in Eastern America which is -4).
However, I'm including PHPExcel files after setting the default timezone with

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

And even with an echo of the time() I do see the correct hour (16:27:39).

Is it a bug of PHPExcel or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the problem: PHPExcel translates to UTC time inside:
PHPExcel/Shared/Date.php

The function PHPToExcel change temporarily the timezone to UTC, and then go back to the default timezone.

The solution is simple but requires to change that file.
Simply copy paste the PHPToExcel function, name it PHPToExcelWithoutUTC (or any name you want) and comment the following lines:

```
//$saveTimeZone = date_default_timezone_get();
//date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

//date_default_timezone_set($saveTimeZone);
```

And it works.

EDIT: It seems it's intended to always use UTC time by default. I'm not deleting this thread because it might be useful for those who want the user timezone.

Comment: It uses UTC because that's a global constant... if we left default timezone as user's timezone, we'd get a myriad of problems, so we assume that all date/time values passed to PHPExcel should be universal time, and if not we convert them to UTC.

Comment: Excel does not convert them, so it's pretty useless?
An excel document is for an end user and has no option of setting the right timezone by itself, it needs a VBA script or some kind of calculation between cell, so if I only want to use one cell for one time, and I want it to have it without any script (since it will ask if I want to enable scripts on the file each time I load it and prevent scrip execution by default): it seems that I can't (except with the solution given here).

Comment: Why are you taking that so badly? I didn't say that you are the worst programmer of the world, PHPExcel is probably the easiest and fun PHP solution for Excel development.
I didn't notice you created this.
I just did not understand why there's no option for non-utc time, I searched on google and other persons had the same problems and some even changed the type (string instead of date) to remove that problem, or they manually changed the input date (in my case I would have to do -4h) to have the time they wanted.

Sorry if you took that so badly. 
Thanks for sharing PHPExcel.

Comment: Convert was probably the wrong word... treat was probably the right word

Comment: I take things badly when it feels like purely negative criticism, and it feels like there's been a lot of that lately: people who say they would have designed or written it so much better, except most of them never take that next step and try to write their own Excel reader/writer, and don't even suggest how they would write it any better (which could then be treated as positive criticism). I know PHPExcel has many flaws, and I try to clear them up when I become aware of them; but there are just days when I feel like I don't want to be somebodys 24x7x365 support line anymore

Comment: In fact I thought it was a bug because of the use of a date_default_timezone_set inside the date examples I picked out of the zip folder of PHPExcel, it was setting Europe/London at the start so I thought it was meant to set the real current timezone for PHPExcel calls, but it didn't.

Anyway I didn't mean to say that it was a bad script, it was just a beginner question. I like the script it's easy to work with it. Thanks for your help and your time.

Comment: @MarkBaker I would suggest a timezone parameter for "PHPToExcel" method, so the developer can decide in what timezone the Excel user should see the time. Currently, "it is up to the developer to ensure that values passed to the date/time conversion 
functions are UST", but I'm passing a timestamp (not a datetime value) which is not in any timezone. So, if I want to see the timestamp's time in +3 timezone (and don't want to change PHPExcel code), I would need to add 3 hours to the timestamp, which theoretically results in having another time point than what I had before.

Comment: @Janis - have you looked at the code or API docs for the ExcelToPHP() and PHPToExcel() methods? They already do have an optional timezone argument. This has been added in the year since this was originally posted

Comment: @MarkBaker You are right, I hadn't looked at the source code. But when I look now, it seems that neither $adjustToTimezone nor $timezone arguments are actually used in PHPToExcel().

Comment: @MarkBaker ExceltoPHP use adjustToTimezone and timezone parameters. But PHPtoExcel doesn't. Is it a known bug?

Comment: @MarkBaker I encountered this issue either. I found that the `PHPToExcel` method accepts extra two arguments - `$adjustToTimezone`, `$timezone`, but the method forgets to utilize them.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of changing the PHPExcel lib, you better add the time difference:

```php
$timeStart + date('Z', $timeStart)
```

For example like that:

```php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

function writeTimeLine($objActiveSheet, &$lineNumber, $timeStart, $timeEnd, 
                       $duration, $category, $client, $date, $comment) {
    
    $objActiveSheet->setCellValue(
        'A' . $lineNumber, 
        PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($timeStart + date('Z', $timeStart))
    );
    
    $objActiveSheet
        ->getStyle('A' . $lineNumber)
        ->getNumberFormat()
        ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME4);
    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Granted rather old, but wanted to supply another solution.

If you're not wanting to edit the library source files, since [`PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel` (1.7.8+)](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.7.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/Date.php#L171) accepts either an integer timestamp or DateTime object, you can easily just convert the integer timestamp to a DateTime object.

Then PHPToExcel will use your DateTime object's timezone when calling $dateValue->format().

The DateTime timezone is only calculated on construct/modify, not on format.

**PHP 5 <= 5.2**

```
$timeStart = new DateTime(date("c", $timeStart));
PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($timeStart);
```

**PHP 5 >= 5.3**

```
$date = new DateTime();
PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($date->setTimestamp($timeStart));
```

**Note**

> The DateTime construct uses the UTC TimeZone when using `'@' . $timestamp`.
>
> `setTimestamp` uses the environments current timezone.
>
> However `setTimestamp` was not made available until 5.3

When developing turnkey solutions, It's generally best practice to try and avoid anything that changes or attempts to determine the environment in which it is deployed.
A good example I often have to fix in other applications is `date('Y-m-d', PHP_INT_MAX);`. Which will work fine on 32-bit system, but not 64-bit (except Windows). Producing unexpected results between different environments.

Answer (score 1):

You may look up to [the source](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/Date.php#L115),

- `ExcelToPHP()` and
- `PHPToExcel()`

also provide parameters so that you may convert the timezone from UTC to yours

```php
/**
 * Convert a date from Excel to PHP
 *
 * @param integer $dateValue             Excel date/time value
 * @param boolean $adjustToTimezone      Flag indicating whether $dateValue should 
 *                                       be treated as
 *                                       a UST timestamp, or adjusted to UST
 * @param string  $timezone              The timezone for finding the adjustment 
 *                                       from UST
 * @return integer                       PHP serialized date/time
 */
public static function ExcelToPHP($dateValue = 0, $adjustToTimezone = false, 
                                  $timezone = null) {
    // 
}
```